# Hide some content in Firebase even for admin

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am doing easy project where is some reputation system. I am wondering is there possibility to make it so even **ME AS ADMIN** can't change those values? I am doing all this with Firebase just to test my skills.

Maybe there is some sort of algorithm to use to make the reputation node part unreadable?

Comment: When you say **Even Admin Can't Change** then who will be authorized to change those values ?

Comment: Only code can change it.

Comment: If you're asking whether you can disable changes from the Firebase Console, the answer is that you can't disable that.